# Terraform - Azure RM - Error: Failed to instantiate provider "azuread" to obtain schema: Unrecognized remote plugin message:

Tags: azure, terraform, init

I'm getting this error when runnig Terraform validate or Terraform plan. What's strange is that the code used to work without a problem from my VsCode terminal window. The same code executes well if run from the Azure Command Shell. Any pointers would be great.

````
Error: Failed to instantiate provider "azuread" to obtain schema: Unrecognized remote plugin message: 

This usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply
needs to be recompiled to support the latest protocol.



Error: Failed to instantiate provider "azurerm" to obtain schema: Unrecognized remote plugin message: 

This usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply
needs to be recompiled to support the latest protocol.```

Here's the provider information:

    ```terraform {
     required_version = "0.12.9"
    }
    provider "azurerm" {
      version = "2.11"
      subscription_id = "my first subscription id goes here"
      features {}
    }
    provider "azurerm" {
      version = "2.11"
      alias           = "shared"
      subscription_id = "my second subscription id goes here"
      features {}
    }
    provider "azuread" {
      version = "0.11.0"
    }```
````

Comment: how about you post some code, such as your provider specification in TF? ;) otherwise helping you might be hard...

Comment: I've tried all possible permutations for provider, even the one used in CloudShell but still go the same error. Here is my provider configuration, I have two azurerm entries since I'm writing to two different subscriptions.

Comment: can you update the used terraform version? 0.12.9 is quite old already. Also, azurerm has newer versions

Answer (score 0):

The same issue resolved for me by using the bellow changes,

First In the main.tf file,

```
provider "azurerm" {
 version = "=2.0.0"
 features { }  
}
```

Second run the upgrade command from Visual Studio Code for deploy the resources,

```
terraform init -upgrade
terraform init
terraform plan
terraform apply
```